# If $(s_n)$ is cauchy, prove or give a counter example for the claim that 1/$s_n$ is cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It is also given that $s_n$ $\neq$ 0. I am thinking that 1/$s_n$ will not be cauchy, but I am not able to think of an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(x_n) = \frac{1}{n}$. It is not hard to show that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy. However $\frac{1}{x_n} = n$.  This clearly cannot be Cauchy since the distance between consecutive terms is constant, namely 1.

Answer (score 1):

Take $s_n = 1/n$

This should provide a counter example ;-)